# Computer hangs on large pickle dump

Tags: python, pickle

Sometimes my computer hang if I am saving large pickle file. How to fix this or replace pickle with something else?

**UPDATE**

Computer is literally hangs, it is not "approaching memory limit". Also this happens not in 100% cases, so it is possible to pickle so large arrays in principle.

**UPDATE 2**

My shame: pickle was not guilty. It was `numpy.stack` called against list of 40000 images.

**UPDATE 3**

No, pickle also hangs, even after `numpy.stack` problem was fixed.

Comment: Try using cPickle instead. `import cPickle as pickle`

Comment: Oh, God, the jokes. And how big of a file? Would you expect a file of comparable size being saved to disk is some other way to take a comparable amount of time?

Comment: Don't be lazy! That's really not much to work with. You could have at least shown some analysis, e.g. ```my memory-consumption approaches 100% and therefore i think my OS is trashing```. Or is ```hang``` a technical-term? :-). And is the problem with ```pickling``` or ```saving```?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `_cpickle` has no suppor fo files larger than 4Gb

Comment: If you're dealing with files over 4GB, there really aren't many options for you...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ anyway, computer should not just hang

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the content of this serialized data, please?

Snippet from pickle manual:

> The pickle module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

So, using pickles may lead to execution of an additional code i.e. endless loop.